# How to generate compiler_command.json using Xcode via CMake

Tags: ios, cmake

I was trying to generate **compile_command.json** file using **CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS** for IOS, but CMake recognize this option CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS only if we use Ninja Generator. "-G Ninja"
and I am using XCode Generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xcodebuild -project path/to/.xcodeproj | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database --output path/for/compile_commands.json